# Retrieving value from a java enum from jni

Tags: java, enums, java-native-interface

From my C code, I would like to access the value of my field tastTrigger:

```
public class ApplicationConfigs {

    public enum TaskTrigger {
        QUEUED, TIMED;

        private final int value;
        private TaskTrigger() {
            this.value = ordinal();
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public static TaskTrigger fromValue(int value)
                throws IllegalArgumentException {
            try {
                return TaskTrigger.values()[value];
            } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown enum value :"+ value);
            }
        }
    }

    private int applicationId;
    private TaskTrigger taskTrigger;
...
```

My JNI code crashes without giving me much hint as to what I am doing wrong.
The first line of code works properly to retrieve the applicationId. What am I missing to get the int value corresponding to taskTrigger?

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_e2e_MainActivity_run(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject callingObject,
        jobject app1Configs) {

    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(app1Configs);

    app1ConfigsC.application_id = env->GetIntField(app1Configs, env->GetFieldID(cls, "applicationId", "I"));  // works just fine

    jmethodID triggerMethod = (env)->GetMethodID( (env)->FindClass(
            "com/example/e2e/ApplicationConfigs$TaskTrigger"), "getValue", "()I");


    jfieldID fieldId = env->GetFieldID(cls, "taskTrigger", "Lcom/example/e2e/ApplicationConfigs/TaskTrigger;");

    jobject objField = env->GetObjectField (app1Configs, fieldId);

    jint value = (env)->CallIntMethod(objField,triggerMethod);
```

***Update***

I tested against NULL each of the returned values and fieldId is NULL.
I tried also

```
    jfieldID fieldId = env->GetFieldID(cls, "taskTrigger", "()com/example/e2e/ApplicationConfigs$TaskTrigger;");
```

but that still returns a NULL.

Comment: You have zero error checking right now. You should do something about that. The signature you use with the second `GetFieldID` looks suspicious, since there's no `$` to indicate a nested class.

Comment: Thanks. Your intuition was right but I am still not sure what the correct expression should be. See my updates.

Comment: There shouldn't be any parentheses in the signature, since it's a field rather than a method. And you're missing the leading `L`.

Comment: That's the first version I had though: env->GetFieldID(cls, "taskTrigger", "Lcom/example/e2e/ApplicationConfigs/TaskTrigger;");

Comment: No, that signature is missing the `$` nested class marker.

Comment: Ah, that worked indeed. Somehow, AS was giving me a warning about that approach and proposing to replace the $ with a / but it did compile with a $ and the code works now. Thank you.